# Is it possible to interpolate a list of dataframes in r?

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, interpolation, purrr

According to the answer of lhs,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467827/11124121

```
#From lhs
library(tidyverse)
data("population")

# create some data to interpolate
population_5 <- population %>% 
  filter(year %% 5 == 0) %>% 
  mutate(female_pop = population / 2,
         male_pop = population / 2)

interpolate_func <- function(variable, data) {
  data %>% 
    group_by(country) %>% 
    # can't interpolate if only one year
    filter(n() >= 2) %>% 
    group_modify(~as_tibble(approx(.x$year, .x[[variable]], 
                                   xout = min(.x$year):max(.x$year)))) %>% 
    set_names(c("country", "year", paste0(variable, "_interpolated"))) %>% 
    ungroup()
}
```

The data that already exists, i.e. year 2000 and 2005 are also interpolated. I want to keep the orginal data and only interpolate the missing parts, that is,

2001-2004 ; 2006-2009

Therefore, I would like to construct a list:

```
population_5_list = list(population_5 %>% filter(year %in% c(2000,2005)),population_5 %>% filter(year %in% c(2005,2010)))
```

And impute the dataframes in the list one by one.

However, a error appeared:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by") :
no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "list"
```

I am wondering how can I change the `interpolate_func` into `purrr` format, in order to apply to list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to loop over the `list` with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(population_5_list,  
   ~ map(vars_to_interpolate, interpolate_func, data = .x) %>% 
        reduce(full_join, by = c("country", "year")))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
# A tibble: 1,266 × 5
   country      year population_interpolated female_pop_interpolated male_pop_interpolated
   <chr>       <int>                   <dbl>                   <dbl>                 <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan  2000               20595360                10297680              10297680 
 2 Afghanistan  2001               21448459                10724230.             10724230.
 3 Afghanistan  2002               22301558                11150779              11150779 
 4 Afghanistan  2003               23154657                11577328.             11577328.
 5 Afghanistan  2004               24007756                12003878              12003878 
 6 Afghanistan  2005               24860855                12430428.             12430428.
 7 Albania      2000                3304948                 1652474               1652474 
 8 Albania      2001                3283184.                1641592.              1641592.
 9 Albania      2002                3261421.                1630710.              1630710.
10 Albania      2003                3239657.                1619829.              1619829.
# … with 1,256 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1,278 × 5
   country      year population_interpolated female_pop_interpolated male_pop_interpolated
   <chr>       <int>                   <dbl>                   <dbl>                 <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan  2005               24860855                12430428.             12430428.
 2 Afghanistan  2006               25568246.               12784123.             12784123.
 3 Afghanistan  2007               26275638.               13137819.             13137819.
 4 Afghanistan  2008               26983029.               13491515.             13491515.
 5 Afghanistan  2009               27690421.               13845210.             13845210.
 6 Afghanistan  2010               28397812                14198906              14198906 
 7 Albania      2005                3196130                 1598065               1598065 
 8 Albania      2006                3186933.                1593466.              1593466.
 9 Albania      2007                3177735.                1588868.              1588868.
10 Albania      2008                3168538.                1584269.              1584269.
# … with 1,268 more rows
```

Comment: One more thing to ask: if I change `data` in interpolate_func <- function(variable, data) into `d` ==> interpolate_func <- function(variable, d), then when I type `map(vars_to_interpolate, interpolate_func, data = .x)`, should I also change `data` into `d`? That is `map(vars_to_interpolate, interpolate_func, d = .x)`.

Comment: @doraemon Yes, it should match the arguments of the function.  In the linked post, you had `data` as argument.  If it is different, you have to change the argument as well as the one inside the body i.e. `data %>%` to `d %>% `

Comment: Would you mind to explain why it works for `map(vars_to_interpolate, interpolate_func, 
    data = population_5)`? Why lhs use `vars_to_interpolate` instead of dataframe...?

Comment: @doraemon IMHO, it is better to give names that are easier to understand for the purpose it serve i..e. if you named data as `d` or `snoopy` etc, it will be hard to read and understand the use of the function and its arguments

Comment: @doraemon I took tht code from `vars_to_interpolate <- names(select(population_5, -country, -year))`.  I thought, each of the dattasets have the same names.  or else you have to use `map(.x %>% select( -country, -year) %>% names, interpolate_func, data = .x)`